# Figuring out how an array is sorted

Tags: arrays

I am given an assignment to create a sortStatus class to return an int 1 if the array is in increasing order, an int -1 if the array is in decreasing order, and int 0 if the array is not sorted in any order.

```
public int sortStatus() {
int flag = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++){
  if(arr[i] <= arr[i+1]){
    flag = 1;
  }
  else if(arr[i] > arr[i+1]){
    flag = -1;
  }
}
return flag;
```

}

This is what I have coded. I cannot find a way to return 0 if the array is not sorted in any order.

Answer (score 0):

you need 2 flags. 1 starts as True to assert the array is asscending. the other starts as True to assert the array is descending. During the loop, if you found they are not the case, change the respective asserts to False. You must loop thru the entire array as this is inherently an O(N) quesiton, except if both asserts are false you can just return out with value 0. In the end, If one of them True you can return 1 or -1, depending on which one has priority (hint: constant array). If both false then the function returns 0